# How can I list the partition table of a currently running esp32 devboard?

Tags: esp8266, esp32, flash-memory

I am developing on an ESP32 devboard (esp8266, wroom). I need to get the partition table *of the currently running device*.

This document contains a quite good documentation of its partition table. I can also read/write flash regions by the `esptool.py` and `parttool.py` tools. These can manage and modify the table well.

However, I did not find a way to read its partitions. How can I do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The current tools of the ESP32 have no explicit option for that. However, the existing tools can be easily combined to do this.

The partition table is located at `0x8000` (32768) on older, and on `0x9000` (36384) on newer systems. Anyways, its location can be found (and be set) at the `CONFIG_PARTITION_TABLE_OFFSET` setting in the menuconfig. Its length is always `0xc00` (3072) bytes.

With the `esptool.py`, this can be read out, for example by the command

```
python $(IDF_PATH)/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py read_flash 0x9000 0xc00 ptable.img
```

And then, the `gen_esp32part.py` tool can be used to convert it to csv to the stdout: `gen_esp32part.py ptable.img`.

For some scripting, these tools can be also combined, for example in a Linux

```
(python $(IDF_PATH)/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py \
  read_flash 0x9000 0xc00 /dev/fd/3 >&2) 3>&1|python \
  $(IDF_PATH)/components/partition_table/gen_esp32part.py /dev/fd/0
```

will dump the table to the stdout.

Comment: On some of the newer ESP32 processors, like the ESP32-S3, the address of the partition table has changed to `0x8000` instead of `0x9000`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm trying the following:

```
gen_esp32part.py partable.bin
```

on a file that is called "partable.bin" which is the extracted partition table using esptool. But gen_esp32part.py keeps throwing the following error:

```
gen_esp32part.py: error: the following arguments are required: input
```

Update:
Nevermind, turns out when typing the script name directly, it gets fed to the pylauncher, which doesn't pass on the arguments. I had to use:

```
python gen_esp32part.py partable.bin
```

then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: idf.py**
If you have an **esp-idf** project you can simply run this command. You must be in your project folder, e.g. *'c:\my-esp32-projects\sample-project'*

```
idf.py partition-table
```

and the partition table will be print in console like this:

```
Partition table binary generated. Contents:
*******************************************************************************
# ESP-IDF Partition Table
# Name, Type, SubType, Offset, Size, Flags
nvs,data,nvs,0x9000,24K,
phy_init,data,phy,0xf000,4K,
factory,app,factory,0x10000,1M,
*******************************************************************************
```

**Option 2: Espressif-IDE**
Use the Espressif-IDE, right-click on your project and choose *ESP-IDF: Partition Table Editor*, this way you have a graphic window where you can view/edit the partition table for your esp32 application
[image]

Comment: This is where you configure the partition table you want to upload. It will not get you the partition table of the currently running device.